# How to reference an endpoint in another one?

Tags: python, eve

In Eve demo, a people collection as endpoint is set up, however there is no id created for it. So if I want to create a endpoint a level up to reference 'people', it seems not easy.

What I want to do for example:

The structure:
company->dept(people)->person

So if I visit www.example.com/company, I get a organized list of people, grouped with dept.

So far I can create person, create different dept(people) endpoints, but how to put all these in a company endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Sub Resources](http://python-eve.org/features#sub-resources) endpoints. The documentation provides the following example:

```
invoices = {
    'url': 'people/<regex("[a-f0-9]{24}"):contact_id>/invoices'
     ...
```

Then you could send a GET like this:

```
people/51f63e0838345b6dcd7eabff/invoices
```

which would roughly translate to: give me all invoices by `<contact_id>`. Follow the link above for detailed explanation of how it works.

**UPDATE after reading the comment**

Since you can have different endpoints all targeting the same datasource, each one with its one filter, you could probably achieve something like that. Both `engineers` and `sales` endpoints would consume a `persons` datasource. One would only return engineers, the other would only return sales people. Then your `departments` endpoint could either be consuming a different datasource (`departments`) and have a data relation on persons, or consume the same persons resource with a filter on a `department` field. Have not tested that, but worth giving it a spin perhaps. See [Advanced Datasource Patterns](http://python-eve.org/config.html#advanced-datasource-patterns).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and great work on Eve! But sub resources does not help me in my specific use case.
So more practical, my question is as below:
I set 'engineers' as an endpoint, then I add persons to this collection, each person will have an id to be referenced later. Then I create another endpoint 'sales' and also add persons to this list. So far so good, I can query and edit both endpoints. But then I want to create another endpoint  'department', which contains 'engineers' and 'sales', e.g. query it will get all persons in a grouped list. How to do this?

Comment: yes, by tag the person with 'role' and 'department' can do the job, however I want to try sth. else. Say for whatever reason I cannot add 'department' tag to person, only 'role' tag. So it's easy to create two lists, one is 'sales' and one is 'engineers', then I want to add these two lists to 'dev' with list id, so it looks like {dev, {sales list id, engineers list id}}, and by querying endpoint 'dev', I get all persons grouped in two lists, with person details included.